# What clothing should I bring to Mt. Titlis in Switzerland during December?

Tags: switzerland, weather-and-climate, clothing

I am visiting Mt. Titlis in Switzerland for a single day between the 15th of December to the 20th of December. The activities would include riding cable car but not skiing. What kind of clothing is required in this duration of the time period?

Comment: Clothing depends a lot on activity. What are you doing there? How long are you planning to stay outside at a time? Are you planning to stay close to populated area or go further away (i.e. if something happens, will you for sure be able to return to warm buildings quickly)?

Comment: Are you climbing the mountain? Riding the cable cars? Going skiing?

Comment: Single day sightseeing, cable car riding. I have modified the question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the Nordic countries, we use a layered clothing method, which has the benefit of being adjustable to the weather:

- First layer: Moisture-wickening technical underclothing

  - Long underpants
  - Long sleeve undershirt
  - Thin socks
- Second layer: Warm and breathable

  - Fleece jacket and underpants, wool socks
  - Thin wool gloves
- Third layer: Outer shell

  - Windproof but breathing jacket and pants
  - Thick waterproof two-finger gloves (separate thumb, and other fingers together)
  - Waterproof shoes (eg. goretex)
  - Wool collar or wool scarf that covers your throat, ears and nose
  - Wool or technical hat (beanie)

The first layer keeps you warm by removing any sweat and humidity (this is the worst type of cold feeling you can get - being wet and cold!). The second layer keeps you warm even in the coldest of weathers. And the third layer keeps wind and water away, which is essential in cold and/or wet snowy weather. And even the best of warm clothes will be cold if the wind can go through it.

The adjustability is helpful, for example if in the morning it is -35 C, but according to the forecast it will warm up to -15 C in the afternoon. Then you just dress up for -35 C in the morning, and in the afternoon, you will probably leave out the second layer.

Or if there is no wind or rain, and plenty of sun, you might leave parts of the outer shell out (probably the wool scarf, and windproof pants).

Or if you sweat so much that your lowest layer is all wet (despite it's moisture-wickening capabilities), you can remove the 1st layer altogether, and stay warm with the dry 2nd and 3rd layer.

Wool and fleece in particular have the added benefit of keeping you warm enough even if they get wet. And they dry very quickly - but keep away from open fire, as they start to burn easily!

Answer (score 17):

Winter mountain night temperatures are comparable with the temperature inside a freezer. Daytime temperatures are no higher than those inside a fridge but can be lower and feel lower still.

You will need serious winter clothes, meant for serious winter weather. And if you are from a warm climate you need extra layers over what locals would wear. Long underpants and a warm long sleeved undershirt at least. Thermo versions might be needed.

On top of that you need a hat, scarf, mittens (or gloves but mittens are warmer) and sun glasses.  Keep your outer clothing well closed, up to your neck, unless you feel hot.
And good boots that keep your feet warm and dry.

Comment: I am from India, a country of warm climate. What kind of shoes will be required: Normal shoes or hiking shoes?

Comment: Hiking boots or snow boots.

Comment: With extra-thick socks.

Comment: no need for extra thick socks if you have good boots.

Answer (score 7):

It depends how long you are staying outside, as tourist I recommend: [I was there several time]

On top, 3 layers are often enough (shirt, pullover, winter jacket), bottom: 2 layers (you can do also with one layer [jeans], as I do it, but if you do not move, depending of winds, it can be cold, I do not recommend it).

As shoes: I recommend the moonboot: light and very effective for keeping heat. But they are just good for simple walking on snow, not for hiking.

Glove, sunglasses, and bonnet is essential.

As tourist, I do not recommend more equipment, and you can heat in restaurant.  But if you want to remain outside several hours (and maybe on evening), you need technical wearing: go in a sport shop and ask. [There is too much risk to get wrong equipment if you just order stuff by "name/type"].

Comment: OP is likely from a hot country (India comes to mind) just jeans will be too cold for people from moderate countries like the UK or northern Germany, for someone from India it is way to little.

Comment: @Willeke: yeah, so I do not recommend it. I also think the OP come from India (you will find 20-30 cars for Indian in Engelberg, and own restaurant). But so, the top visit is mostly a selfie on the terrace, and eventually a walk in the ice cave, walking distance to the restaurant, for heating "break". Some will have some heavy blanket provided by the tours (you cannot imagine how many will have the inappropriate wearing, but nobody will die (or become ill). Gloves and good shoes are the most important item. (wet shoes!)

Comment: @Willeke Why do you guess the OP is from India?

Comment: @Willeke You are right!! I am from India

Answer (score 6):

(according to the precision you just made)

It is difficult to answer.

If you just want to go up the mountain, look around, take a couple of pictures, you don't need the whole layers thing and technical winter equipments; you will not stay out that long.

I would have regular winter boots; I don't think you will want to venture out and hike; so no need for specialized hiking boots.

Also a regular winter coat, no need for a fancy technical and expensive winter coat if you will be using it for just a couple of hours (remember that down in the valley it will not be that cold).

Also a good hat and a pair of winter gloves; maybe a scarf if your coat does not cover your neck.

Answer (score 5):

It's winter and the elevation of Titlis is 3238 meter. That means the temperatures will be far below 0° C, and it might snow. Bring winter clothes (i.e. a thick jacket, hiking boots if you have them) or ski clothes if you want to go skiing.